# Adding a loader image/text in Bootstrap X-editable

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

How can I put a loader gif in X-editable while an update request is made?

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#username').editable();
});

<a href="#" id="username">superuser</a>

$('#username').editable({
    type: 'text',
    pk: 1,
    url: '/post',
    title: 'Enter username'
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X-editable comes with a loader gif by default.

Just make sure the loader gif is the following path:

```
/img/loading.gif
```

If you wish to provide a custom path to the loader.gif,

Modify the following lines in the `editable-form.css` file, `line 42`:

```
.editableform-loading {  
    background: url('../img/loading.gif') center center no-repeat;  
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks Mysteryos! It's works for me. Modified the css file and used custom path.